# Как вывести посты одной категории выбранной таксономии?

Tags: php, wordpress

Вивожу категории:

```
$arg_cat = array(
  'orderby'      => 'name',
  'order'        => 'ASC',
  'exclude'      => '',
  'include'      => '',
  'taxonomy'     => 'portfolio-exsys-cat-ru',
);

$categories = get_categories( $arg_cat );

// echo $categories[1]->name;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($categories);
echo "</pre>";
```

**вот мои категории**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно вывести все посты этой категории (пробую по [slug] => ventilyaciya, но ничего не получаетса...)

вот так:

```
$args_work = array( 
        'category_name' => "ventilyaciya",
        'post_type' => 'portfolio-exsys-ru',
);

$posts_work = get_posts($args_work);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($posts_work);
echo "</pre>";
```

Приходит пусто...

Answer (score 0):

Категории - это для постов. Надо указывать таксономию и её термины. Подробнее [здесь](http://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#parametry-taksonomij).

В общем, попробуйте так:

```
$args_work = array(
    'portfolio-exsys-ru' => 'ventilyaciya',
    'post_type'          => 'portfolio-exsys-ru',
);

$posts_work = get_posts( $args_work );

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $posts_work );
echo '</pre>';
```